# Undefined method when accessing hash element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

Hash:

```
p: {:headline=>"Managing Director at Test company name", :pid=>"0tSsRvCR7r", :first_name=>"John", :last_name=>"Doe", :industry=>"Financial Services", :summary=>nil, :public_profile_url=>"http://www.linkedin.com/pub/john-doe/7a/78/606", :distance=>0}
```

Attempting to call p.pid but getting the error:

```
EXCEPTION: undefined method `pid' for #<Hash:0x007fcf1b3a29f0>
```

All other elements can be accessed fine. Also tried different names for the field but to no avail. Can anyone shed some light on this please? Really hoping it's not one of those bugs that you stare at for ages only to realise it's something silly :/.

Note: I have also tried p['pid']. This didn't work either. Relatively new to Rails.

Comment: Use `p[:pid]` for Hashes, with HashWithIndifferentAccess you can either use the symbol :pid or the string 'pid' to acces the value: `p['pid']` or `p[:pid]` should work for HashWithIndifferentAccess

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
p = {:headline=>"Managing Director at Test company name", :pid=>"0tSsRvCR7r", :first_name=>"John",     :last_name=>"Doe", :industry=>"Financial Services", :summary=>nil,     :public_profile_url=>"http://www.linkedin.com/pub/john-doe/7a/78/606", :distance=>0}
puts p
puts p[:pid]
```

[hash docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html)

[more on hashes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm)

Comment: Well, that fixes the problem, but why was it a problem to begin with? I thought `hash.key` and `hash[:key]` were synonymous?

Comment: You don't get those nice methods from a hash, unfortunately. If you need to access keys with a method, you can use an [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) from the Ruby standard library.